# Animate Jquery .load()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I know this will be easy for somebody that knows jQUERY. I have recently started learning and struggling to animate the results that are being loaded via AJAX. Im wanting in to fade in. Where would i put this code in?

```
 fadeIn("slow")
```

here is my ajax loader:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var file_name = 'test.php';
 $("div#mybox").load(file_name,function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr), {
 if(statusTxt=="error")
 // bla bla
 });
 });
```

Your help is much appreciated :)
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put your "animation" code inside the success callback function of ajax.

```
success : function (data) { [animationcodehere] }
```

**Update:**
With load function you can do it like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var file_name = 'test.php';
 $("div#mybox").load(file_name,function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr), function() {
   $("div#mybox").fadeIn('slow');
  });
 });
```